# Amazon EC2 IO operations

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a question regarding EC2.

Let's say I have a pure EC2 instance with no EBS volumes attached. For small instance type I still have 160 GB of data (which is lost on error, etc).

The question is if I pay for IO operations to these 160GB drive?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't have to pay exclusively for I/O operation on EC2 machine.

You are just paid for the data-transfer to the world and EC2 (client/server) + EC2 instance on an hour (I hope you know all this), in-case if you don't take a look at this: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/.

Also, there is a nice tool provided by Amazon AWS to calculate your spending on AWS - take a look at it here: http://aws.amazon.com/calculator/.

Comment: thank you. was sure about IO to ec2, but it is always better to recheck

Answer (score 0):

It does charge money for io request. here is from the site. It charged for me, I am not sure for you tho. I found the io the very expensive. I have a simple blog with normal traffic, postgresql backend. That cost me like 25 bucks every month only for io access. After I found out that, I switched.

Amazon EBS Standard volumes

```
$0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage
$0.10 per 1 million I/O requests
```

Amazon EBS Provisioned IOPS volumes

```
$0.125 per GB-month of provisioned storage
$0.10 per provisioned IOPS-month
```

Amazon EBS Snapshots to Amazon S3

```
$0.095 per GB-month of data stored
```